# Lag 1 Scatter Plot in R

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, scatter-plot, autocorrelation

I have an assignment. There are two datasets and in one of the questions, I needed to find the lag 1 scatter plot of each time series.

I created the graphs, but my question is what does it tell us? I know we are looking for some sort of autocorrelation, yet I couldn't properly understand it. What can we infer from this scatter plot and how can we make any inference?

To give you a better understanding I added one of the dataset and its graph, as well.

[image: Dataset]

[image: Graph]

**Edit**

Data and graph code.

```
x <- c(39,35,16,18,7,22,13,18,20,9,-12,-11,-19,-9,-2,16)
plot(dplyr::lag(x), x)
```

The graph can also be plotted with

```
tsDyn::autopairs(x, type = "points")
```

Comment: The graph doesn't show randomness, it doesn't show seasonality but there might be reasons to suspect a correlation. Run `summary(lm(x ~ dplyr::lag(x)))` to see that the coefficient of the lagged series is probably not zero. R2 is not big, though.

Comment: Also, I have voted to migrate this question to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), since it seems to be more a question about statistics than about R code.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you for your response. But how could you make inference about randomness, seasonality or correlation? Did you run the code you wrote and analysed the result or by intuition? If intuition, I would like to improve it as well, which subject do you think I should research?

Comment: First of all, visual inspection. But this kind of analysis comes with practice. After seeing many such graphs you will see that there is an upward trend, sort of. Then there are the analytic methods, ACF and PACF, regression, etc. See, for instance, [here](https://www.statisticshowto.com/lag-plot/).